# ubuntu eclipse beaglebone debugging not work

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, beagleboard

I have the beaglebone connected to my PC running virtual Ubuntu (12.10) via VMware. I tried to debug my C++ codes on beaglebone using Eclipse (Version 3.8).

I followed the youtube video :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFv_-ykLppo. But I was not able to get the debugging work properly. Can somebody help me?

Below is what I did and what I got. Note: My host PC's IP is 192.168.1.105. The beaglebone's IP is 192.168.102.

1. Beaglebone is conntec to PC through USB and ethernet. I was able to open the connection with Beaglebone in the embedded terminals of Eclipse.
2. I successfully installed gdb-multiarch in my local PC by entering this command in the PC's terminal:                 sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch.
3. I successfully installed gdbserver on beaglebone by entering this command in the beaglebone's terminal :       sudo apt-get install gdbserver
4. I CD to the application folder and entered this command in the beaglebone's terminal:                                       gdbserver [hostPC's IP]:12346 HelloWorldTest4 
   I got this response:
   Processing HelloWorldTest4 created; pid=1035
   Listening on port 12346
5. In Eclipse, I go to Run->Debug Configurations->, Below is what I configured and they are also shown in the attached screen shots.
   Main - > Build(if required ) before launching: Build configurations: Debug; Use workspacesettings
   Debugger-> Main-> GDB debugger:          gdb-multiarch
                                    GDB command file :  .gdbinit
   Debugger-> Gdbserver Settings-> Gdbserver name: [beaglebone's IP address]
                                                           Port number :12346
6. Then I clicked Debug, I got the following errors.
   POP-UP windows: 'Launching HelloWorldTest4 Debug' has encountered a problem. Error in final launch sequence:
   In Console: warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description

Questions:
1. Is this problem related to gdb-multiarch? How to fix it?
2. Is my IP addresses specified corectly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the same problem by creating a .gdbinit file with the following content in my project folder:

set architecture arm

then point the  Debug Configuration -> Debugger -> GDB command file entry to this new .gdbinit file and debug

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem,
I download gdb source code, recompiled for target arm, and copy gdb to `arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb` and in eclipese I changed gdb to `arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb`. And everything started working.

get gdb (7.8) sources and extract them

```
./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --with-expat=/usr/local/lib/
make
cd gdb/gdbserver
/configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --with-expat=/usr/local/lib/
make
```